# How To Identify days before and after a holiday within pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date

*Objective*: to identify 2 days before the holiday and 3 days after a holiday by making things binary.

*Details*: Specifically I am trying to get a result to df['is_2_days_before'] and df['is_3_days_after'] with a TRUE or FALSE.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar as calendar

dr = pd.date_range(start='2015-07-01', end='2015-07-31')
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = dr

cal = calendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start=dr.min(), end=dr.max())

df['holiday'] = df['Date'].isin(holidays)
df
```

The above code simply identifies which dates are holidays.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need to using `DateOffset`

```
df['2 day before holiday'] = df['Date'].isin(holidays-pd.DateOffset(2))
df['3 day after holiday'] = df['Date'].isin(holidays+pd.DateOffset(3))
```